# Как грамотно реализовать триггер копирования данных из одной таблицы в другую в mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть две идентичные таблицы table1 и table2, все столбцы одинаковые (column1, column2,..., column6). В table1 постоянно записываются данные, получаемые в результате выполнения программы на python. Необходимо копировать и вставлять строку из table1 в table2 при выполнении определённого условия, например, если таблице table1 появляется строка в которой column4 отличается от заданного значения (column4 not like 250), осуществляется запись этой строки в table1. Использую phpmyadmin.
Пробывал в теле триггера:
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column4 not like 250.
Триггер срабатывает, но закидывает все строки, а не конкретную последнюю удовлетворяющую условию.

Comment: во первых операции like/not like служат для поиска в строках, а не для работы с числами. Во вторых запрос в триггере выполняется точно так же как выполнился бы и без триггера. А запрос с данным where действительно переписывает все строки (ну кроме тех что каким то чудом таки не попали под like). В триггерах же надо работать с _текущей_ строкой, поля которой доступны через NEW.имя-поля

Comment: В теле триггера надо брать не записи из таблицы, а значения из псевдотаблицы NEW - т.е. только из вставленной строки.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ai_table1
AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, ... columnN)
    SELECT NEW.column1, ... , NEW.columnN 
    WHERE NEW.column4 != 250;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо,  все заработало! Трудимся дальше.